# Create dynamic form fields using jquery and backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an application which uses backbone js and jquery. I need to generate templates dynamically based on what response i get from the server. The scenario is like this... I have a dropdown of templates which I can choose, after I select any template from the dropdown, an api is called for that template which provides me with a structure like this

```
items:[
{
    "vars":
           {
               "name":
                      {
                           "required": false,
                           "default": "abc"
                      },
               "address":
                      {
                           "required": false,
                           "default": "xyz"
                       }
           }
    "tables": {}
}]
```

So how can I create dynamic form elements using this kind of server response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [backbone-forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms) plugin, and map your server response to a form object. Something like:

```
var data = {};
var schema = {};
var item = _.first(items);

_.each(item.vars, function(value, key) {
  data[key] = value.default;
  schema[key] = {
    type:"Text",
    validators:value.required ? ['required'] : undefined
  };
});

var form = new Backbone.Form({data:data, schema:schema}).render();
```

That's just a simple, untested example. Check out the `backbone-forms` documentation, and see if it can do what you need.

Comment: What if I want to do it without using the backbone forms?

Comment: @SuchitaDoshi, then I guess you can write the code that takes in your server response and creates forms from it? Unless you want to use an existing product, there's not many tips to give. It's pretty simple.

Comment: So if i use backbone forms, it will not always be the case where i will have to create textboxes, I would also need dropdowns for example if I get a response like "do you want to subscribe?":
                   {
                       "required": false,
                       "provider": "Yes"
                   }, I will have to make this as a dropdown instead of checkbox...

Comment: Backbone.Forms supports many kinds of form elements. Check out the documentation. For simple form its trivial to implement the form generation without the plugin as well, that was just my first idea.